# Kotlin generic casting to a more specific subclass

Tags: java, android, generics, kotlin, mvp

So I'm trying to mess with Kotlin and I have an old java MVP framework with sort of poor generics in java where we had to cast a generic interface to a more specific one, like 
`public <P extends BaseContract.Presenter> P getPresenter()`

Which we would cast in a subclass as

```
@Override
public AdvertisementContract.Presenter getPresenter()
{
    return (AdvertisementContract.Presenter)super.getPresenter();
}
```

In Kotlin I'm going for this:

```
override fun getPresenter(): AdvertisementContract.Presenter
{
    return super.getPresenter() as AdvertisementContract.Presenter
}
```

Is there anything I can do without fixing the generics in the base interface?

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding of your question, you could do it like this,

```
override fun <P: BaseContract.Presenter> getPresenter(): P {
    return mPresenter
}
```

Where mPresenter could be instance of Any Presenter extending `BaseContract.Presenter` class